# Continuous Loop/Repeat causes Excel to Crash (after hours/days)

Tags: vba, excel, repeat, freeze

I have some VBA code that runs every 15 minutes continually. This code runs fine at first but after a period of time (which varies from around 4 hours to 5 days) Excel crashes.

It is not a VBA crash (with debug option) but it is Excel freezing and saying the application needs to be restarted.

Am I trying to use Excel in a way it was not designed for? Should I be clearing some memory/cache to avoid this?

Comment: could you post the code?  The explanations could vary.  Also, some system specs of the machine in question.

Comment: Maybe try using a Windows Scheduled Task instead.  You can have your macro auto-run when the file opens.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is due to a fail of the *OnTime* method of the application, I had your same problem some time ago with an Excel tool which was scraping data from the web every 5 minutes. Sometimes it just crashed with no specific log or error/warning. Here is the workaround I have implemented:

1) In the **Workbook_Open** event I have put :

```
myMacro 'the call to my procedure when the workbook is opened
ThisWorkbook.Save 'I was saving the results, I don't know if you need this
ThisWorkbook.Close 'I was closing my Workbook
```

2) In the Windows system, I was using a tool (installed usually with the system) called **Task Scheduler**, whose executable lies into the system folder (*C:\Windows\System32\taskschd.msc*) and it's really intuitive and easy-to-use. I have scheduled a task every 5 minutes which consisted on [opening the workbook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ce659a72-88e1-448b-8b45-ff2cb4ba9da8/starting-excel-file-with-task-scheduler) (once this was done, the open-workbook-event macro was triggered so my procedure was called, and after its execution the Workbook was closed and saved with the two lines of code I have posted you above).

Even if this is just my opinion (that I cannot prove with technical evidences), I don't trust too much the `Application.OnTime` in the long-term; it works fine for a little task every 10 seconds for a few minutes, but when the macro should be running regularly and you want to avoid seeing that, once every 5 hours, the Excel process crashes... then I would suggest to let the scheduling task to the Microsot tool rather than to the Excel application method.

**MY EXPERIENCE**
- my Excel, with the `OnTime` method in the macro, was crashing in a period between 1 hour (minimum crash) and 7 hours (maximum length of time before crashing). I was forced to open a distance connection from home and running it in the morning before to go out, to make sure the job was done before I got at work. 
- my *same* macro, with the procedure I have described you above, **never** crashed anymore. I believe the system process is much more reliable than the Excel's one (but again, I don't have any evidence to prove you this so don't take it as gold).